# Stored procedure to get the next record and update the status of the row

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a stored procedure (below) that will read the next row to process, set the row status to 1 (in process), and return the GUID that identifies the row.  Does this procedure achieve the goal?  Is there a better way?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [PSR].[uspGetNextAssessmentEvent]
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRAN T1;

    WITH T AS
    (
    SELECT TOP (1) TransactionGuid,ItemStatus
    FROM [PSR].[PersonAssessmentEventStore]
        WHERE ItemStatus=0
        ORDER BY CreateDttm
    )
    UPDATE T
    SET ItemStatus = 1
    OUTPUT INSERTED.TransactionGuid

COMMIT TRAN T1;

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is just fine. OUTPUT is good for this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Is there a specific benefit to using the CTE?

Comment: UPDATE doesn't support ORDER BY, so to get the first row, you need a subquery. The CTE makes for a nicer subquery experience.